# Is there a way i can stop my output from repeated printing?

Tags: python

How can I stop my code from repeated output printing
Below is the code:

```
def get_complement(str):
    '''
    (str) -> str

    Return the nucleotide's complement.

    >>>get_complement('ATT')
    'TAA'
    >>>get_complement('CGCC')
    'GCGG'
    >>>get_complement('ATG')
    'TAC'
    >>>get_complement('TCAG')
    'AGTC'
    >>>get_complement('ATCG')
    'TAGC'

    '''
    for i in str:
        if (i == 'A'):print('T', end = "")
        elif (i == 'T'):print('A', end = "")
        elif (i == 'C'):print('G', end = "")
        elif (i == 'G'):print('C', end = "")
print(get_complement(str))
```

Comment: So what `"repeated output printing"` are you referring to?

Comment: Your function _prints_ the complements, but doesn't _return_ anything, so the final `print(get_complement(str))` will not print anything. And by the way please do not give the name `str` to a variable or function parameter, you are shadowing a built-in Python class

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you should do something like this:

```
nucleotide_complement_map = {
    "A": "T",
    "T": "A",
    "C": "G",
    "G": "C"
}

def get_complement(s):
    '''
    (str) -> str

    Return the nucleotide's complement.

    >>>get_complement('ATT')
    'TAA'
    >>>get_complement('CGCC')
    'GCGG'
    >>>get_complement('ATG')
    'TAC'
    >>>get_complement('TCAG')
    'AGTC'
    >>>get_complement('ATCG')
    'TAGC'

    '''

    return "".join([nucleotide_complement_map[c] for c in s])

s = 'ATT'
print(get_complement(s))
```

I also changed name of parameter "str", because that is a built-in name in python and shouldn't be used as a name of parameter

Comment: @OmolloFelix Great, could you accept the answer then?